# Comparing two dataset in Pig

Tags: apache-pig

I'm trying to compare two datasets in pig.

```
A = Load 'file' using pigstorage('|') (id : chararray, id1: charray, id2 : charray, name: charray, name1 : chararray, adr : chararray);

B = Load 'file1' using pigstorage('|') (id : chararray, id1: charray, id2 : charray);
```

Suppose i have above schema where the combination of from file 1(id,id1,id2) should be equal to combination of (id,id1,id2) from file 2.

And after the comparision is.I want to store the output where combination is matched as 
(id : chararray, id1: charray, id2 : charray, name: charray, name1 : chararray, adr : chararray)

Also i want to know how to output the results for the combinations that are not matched to a separate file also.

Can anyone help me with that. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `JOIN` to find matching combination. (I used LEFT OUTER JOIN to get both MATCHED and NON_MATCHED)

```
A = Load 'file1' using PigStorage('|') as (id : chararray, id1: chararray, id2 : chararray, name: chararray, name1 : chararray, adr : chararray);

B = Load 'file2' using PigStorage('|') as (id : chararray, id1: chararray, id2 : chararray);

C = JOIN A BY (id, id1, id2) LEFT OUTER, B BY (id, id1, id2);
```

And then, use `SPLIT` to separate MATCHED and NOT_MATCHED.

```
SPLIT C INTO MATCHED IF B::id is not null, NOT_MATCHED IF B::id is null;
```

Comment: Does split requires variable ?? and Can we store Split directly ?

Comment: @dk3094 syntax of split is 
SPLIT alias INTO alias IF expression, alias IF expression [, alias IF expression …];   you can store MATCHED and NOT_MATCHED separately.